# Output blank in ListSurfacePlot3D

Tags: plotting

I'm pretty new to Mathematica and assume I am overlooking something simple. I am attempting to reproduce the code below. It is my understanding that the format is from an older version of Mathematica.
[image]

The data for t1 I got is shown below and looks to be in the correct format. Yet my graph is blank every time I try. I do not have any parameters set here and was just attempting to get an output.
[image]

Thank you for your time.

Full code below,

```
enter code here
ClearAll["Global`*"];
TB = 100; TR = 200; TT = 300; TL = 400; W = 2; L = 1; M = 10; dy = W/(M - 1);

eqns = Join[Table[T[i]''[x] + (T[i + 1][x] + T[i - 1][x] - 2 T[i][x])/dy^2 == 
0, {i, 3, M - 2}],{T[2]''[x] + (T[3][x] + TB - 2 T[2][x])/dy^2 == 0, T[M - 1]''[x] + (TT + T[M - 2][x] - 2 T[M - 1][x])/dy^2 == 0}, Table[{T[i][0] == TL, T[i][L] == TR}, {i, 2, M - 1}]];

AbsoluteTiming[sol = NDSolve[eqns, Table[T[i], {i, 2, M - 1}], {x, 0, L}];]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[T[i][x] /. sol, {i, 2, M - 1, 3}]], {x, 0, L}]

t1 = Flatten[Table[{yj = (j - 1) dy, xi = L (i - 1)/(M - 1), 
T[j][xi] /. sol}, {j, 2, M - 1}, {i, 1, M}], {2}]

up = ListSurfacePlot3D[t1]
```

Comment: Could you, please, post your code rather than a screenshot so we can copy and paste? Many thanks!

Comment: The problem may be with the way you are flattening the table.  Try `t1 = Flatten[Table[ ... ], 1]` instead.

Comment: Code has been added @bmf.

Comment: Similar result when I restructure the flattening @LouisB.

Comment: I get an error `NDSolve::ndnco` from `NDSolve`. Don't you?  The problem seems to be with `NDSolve` and nothing to do with the image-code you quote.

Comment: After fixing several syntax errors, I get the same error.  Your system of equations has no initial conditions.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I made a mistake in copying the code over and left out the initial conditions. It should run now.

Comment: @bbgodfrey ^. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll notice in the docs for `NDSolve` the use of `First[sol]` or `First[NDSolve[..]]`.  This is because `NDSolve` returns a solution **set** (since nonlinear systems may have multiple solutions).  If you look at your original `t1`, it has entries like `{x, y, {z}}` with extra braces.  `First@sol` fixes this.  Also, `t1` needed further flattening for `ListSurfacePlot`.

```
t1 = Flatten[
  Table[{yj = (j - 1) dy, xi = L (i - 1)/(M - 1), 
    T[j][xi] /. First@sol}, {j, 2, M - 1}, {i, 1, M}], {2}]

up = ListSurfacePlot3D[Flatten[t1, 1], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]